# Creating an dropdown menu using a Vue instance

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I switched from React to Vue and for me there are some incomprehensible nuances I want to create a drop-down menu, but I have some incomprehensible things related to this who is familiar with React knows that you can create a certain property with a boolean value inside a state or using hooks then when clicking on the buttons, use setState and manage with it,

I understand that you can implement something like this in Vue JS, but I am confused by one question, how can you create a certain property in Vue JS? is it possible to instantiate by type `let app = new Vue({el: '#app',});` for each component? Because I don't understand how to create a property for example `showDropDown` without using `new Vue ({})`?

My code at the moment looks like this

```
<template>
    <div>
      <button class="arrow_down dropbtn">
        Read More
        <img src="arrow-down.png" alt="arrow-down">
      </button>
      <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#"><li>Gagging</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>Multiple BJs</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>Deep Throat</li></a>
      </div>
    </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
   .dropdown-content {
     display: none;
   }
</style>

<script>
  export default {
    name: "ClosePage",
  }
</script>
```

I think the question is clear, I want to know how, when clicking on a button with an `arrow_down` class, to show a drop-down menu and, in the same way, when clicking again, close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Options API, you can create local reactive state in Vue components by declaring them in [`data`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#data):

```html
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      showDropDown: false
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Use that state in your template to conditionally show an element with [`v-if`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-if):

```html
<div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content" v-if="showDropDown">
 ...
</div>
```

Use [`v-on`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-on) to add a `click`-handler to the button that toggles the dropdown state:

```html
<button @click="showDropDown = !showDropDown">Read More</button>
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/QWdGrRB)